# jQuery check if browser support position: fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I check if browser supports `position:fixed` using jQuery. I assume I have to use `$.support` I think, but how?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you tell us why you need this, we may be able to give you a workaround for whatever you're doing.

Comment: I want to detect if the browser supports fixed, if yes then fine else I will use some ugly hack to position the element.

Comment: Would it be easier to just append a class to the Element's className and then handle your hack in a stylesheet?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The most reliable way would be to actually feature-test it. Browser sniffing is fragile and unreliable.

I have an example of such test in CFT http://kangax.github.com/cft/#IS_POSITION_FIXED_SUPPORTED. Note that the test should be run after `document.body` is loaded.

Comment: Great example, and great site, btw!

Comment: unfortunately this test returns a false positive in MobileSafari, where position:fixed is not supported

Comment: I have the same problem as Alec, but as prendio2 notes, this test is unfortunately not correct for MobileSafari. Though great otherwise!

Comment: Hi! I think your feature tests are great.  What are your terms for usage of your stuff? :)  I'd gladly attribute it to you, if that's all it takes. :D  Thanks!

Comment: Nikki, attribution is fine. Feel free to use it for whatever you need it.

Comment: @prendio2 MobileSafari issue should now be fixed. Thanks.

Comment: This seems to work correctly in MobileSafari in iOS 4.2 (showing a negative result), but also shows the same result for iOS 5beta, where position:fixed behaviour has been updated.

Answer (score 2):

I find that mobile safari (specifically iOS 4.2 via the iOS Simulator on OSX) refuses to scroll anywhere unless you wait a few miliseconds.  Hence the false positive.

I wrote a quick jquery plugin to work around it:

```
(function($) {
  $.support.fixedPosition = function (callback) {
    setTimeout(
      function () {
        var container = document.body;
        if (document.createElement && container && container.appendChild && container.removeChild) {
          var el = document.createElement('div');
          if (!el.getBoundingClientRect) return null;
          el.innerHTML = 'x';
          el.style.cssText = 'position:fixed;top:100px;';
          container.appendChild(el);
          var originalHeight = container.style.height,
              originalScrollTop = container.scrollTop;
          container.style.height = '3000px';
          container.scrollTop = 500;
          var elementTop = el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
          container.style.height = originalHeight;
          var isSupported = !!(elementTop === 100);
          container.removeChild(el);
          container.scrollTop = originalScrollTop;
          callback(isSupported);
        }
        else {
          callback(null);
        }
      }, 
      20
    );
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function fixedcheck () {
    var fixedDiv = $('<div>').css('position', 'fixed').appendTo('body');
    var pos1 = fixedDiv.offset().top;
    $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() + 1);
    var pos2 = fixedDiv.offset().top;
    fixedDiv.remove();
    return (pos1 != pos2)
}

/* Usage */
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (!fixedcheck()) alert('Your browser does not support fixed position!')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if position exists by making a code like this:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
test = function() {
if(!!document.getElementById("test").style.position) {
alert('true');
}
else{
alert('false');
}
}
</script>

<body>
<p id="test" onclick="test();" style="position:fixed;">Hi</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Since position exists in all main browser this will always return true. I imagine there isn't a way to check the possible values of position, so you'll have to check which browser and which version the user are viewing your page as Paolo Bergantino said.

Answer (score 0):

`position:fixed` apparently works for all block elements in Mobile Safari (4.3.2) except body, so the CFT answer (http://kangax.github.com/cft/#IS_POSITION_FIXED_SUPPORTED) should have this in it:

`var isSupported = (container.scrollTop === 500 && elementTop === 100);`

Answer (score 0):

The feature-test [Position fixed support](http://kangax.github.com/cft/#IS_POSITION_FIXED_SUPPORTED) , mentioned above, returns a false-positive on Opera Mini (which does not support position: fixed).

Answer (score 0):

I've created another check if `position:fixed` is really supported in browser. It creates fixed div and try to scroll and check if the position of div changed.

```
function isPositionFixedSupported(){
    var el = jQuery("<div id='fixed_test' style='position:fixed;top:1px;width:1px;height:1px;'></div>");
    el.appendTo("body");

    var prevScrollTop = jQuery(document).scrollTop();
    var expectedResult = 1+prevScrollTop;
    var scrollChanged = false;

    //simulate scrolling
    if (prevScrollTop === 0) {
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
        expectedResult = 2;
        scrollChanged = true;
    }

    //check position of div
    suppoorted = (el.offset().top === expectedResult);

    if (scrollChanged) {
        window.scrollTo(0, prevScrollTop);
    }

    el.remove();

    return suppoorted;
}
```

This function was tested in Firefox 22, Chrome 28, IE 7-10, Android Browser 2.3.