# How to detect lack of position:fixed in a generic way?

Tags: css, ipad, mobile, viewport

On mobile devices such as the iPad, I would like to disable a feature that only works if position:fixed is supported. Is there a way to detect these devices without using the user agent string? The reason is that I would like to avoid searching for iPad, iPhone, iPod, Android, etc if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Run the following function to test for `position:fixed` support.

```
function () {
  var isSupported = null;
  if (document.createElement) {
      var el = document.createElement("div");
      if (el && el.style) {
          el.style.position = "fixed";
          el.style.top = "10px";
          var root = document.body;
          if (root && root.appendChild && root.removeChild) {
              root.appendChild(el);
              isSupported = el.offsetTop === 10;
              root.removeChild(el);
          }
      }
  }
  return isSupported;
}
```

From http://kangax.github.com/cft/#IS_POSITION_FIXED_SUPPORTED

Comment: Apparently this returns a false positive in Mobile Safari (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973875/jquery-check-if-browser-support-position-fixed).

Comment: Why not simply set a position:fixed on some element and then read it back? If position:fixed not supported returned value, should not be equal to fixed in theory...

Answer (score 0):

also returns a false-positive on Opera Mini.

*Why not simply set a position:fixed on some element and then read it back? If position:fixed not supported returned value, should not be equal to fixed in theory*

that does not work on Opera Mini: you can set position to "fixed", it will read as "fixed" even though it is not supported.