# Checking the support for a css property attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cross-browser

I want to test if a particular css property attribute is supported in the browser. For a css property, i can do it like

```
document.createElement("detect").style["-webkit-overflow-scrolling"] === ""
```

But what if i have to check for a particular class or attribute. For example, i want to test the support for

```
position:fixed
```

How can i do that(apart from using Modernizr)? Pls help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function isFixedSupported() {
  var isSupported = null;
  if (document.createElement) {
      var el = document.createElement("div");
      if (el && el.style) {
          el.style.position = "fixed";
          el.style.top = "10px";
          var root = document.body;
          if (root && root.appendChild && root.removeChild) {
              root.appendChild(el);
              isSupported = el.offsetTop === 10;
              root.removeChild(el);
          }
      }
  }
  return isSupported;
}

var canUseFixed = isFixedSupported(); //true:false
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/zyCLt/)

Comment: You could at least link to http://kangax.github.com/cft/#IS_POSITION_FIXED_SUPPORTED

Comment: I've been using this for a long time and don't remember exactly where I first got it, but I don't think it was there, probably one of the other hundred sites that has this function, like right here on SO after a little searching : [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911866/how-to-detect-lack-of-positionfixed-in-a-generic-way). If it originates from Kangax, I don't know, probably ?

Comment: There's another version [here](http://tadhg.com/wp/2007/03/29/checking-for-positionfixed-support/), and a Google search gives 16 million results for similar functions.

Comment: Nope, returns the `<body>` for me in chrome ? [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/zyCLt/1/)

Comment: yeah, i was checking it before there was anything at all in the body :|   works fine if i put something in the body and run this. :)