# Detect iOS5 within mobile Safari (javascript preferred)

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, mobile, safari

The new fixed positioning introduced in iOS5 corrupted my webapp and I need a way to detect iOS5 users.

How can I detect iOS5? What is the browser agent string? JavaScript preferred. Thanks!

Comment: Sites should *NEVER* use browser agent strings to determine behavior.

Comment: I have it specified for other mobile devices that support it such as android, and I used javascript to reposition some elements using touch events to replicate fixed positioning on iphones lack of position fixed, so now that ios5 has position fixed it seems to not be behaving normally.

Comment: So basically, you don't want to detect iOS 5, instead you want to detect support for position: fixed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery check if browser support position: fixed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973875/jquery-check-if-browser-support-position-fixed)

Comment: Hrm, I may have picked the wrong one to dupe. A comment says that test doesn't work right in MobileSafari. But there are a few similar questions as well.

Comment: @Kevin, I think you might be a bit off base here. In general I can agree but how would you make this work without checking the user-agent? Never is a strong word if you can't provide a working alternative.

Comment: @Kevin, in the mobile world, browser detection is somewhat of a necessity...a nokia is not a blackberry os5 device is not an iOS device. On the plus side, the mobile world is increasingly moving towards the webkit platform.

Comment: If you need to differentiate based on what features the browser supports, use feature detection. Looking at user agent strings is precisely why the user agent string is such a mess and why every browser lies about what they really are.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[From the SO question: *What is the iOS 5 user-agent string*:](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7825873/836407)

iPhone:

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3

iPad:

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3

And here is way to test for ios 5.x in javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/OS 5(_\d)+ like Mac OS X/i))
        // this helps detect minor versions such as 5_0_1
        document.write("You have iOS 5! Aren't you special!");
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the user-agent string.

Comment: the agent strings that i am detecting for ios5 are coming back with another revision number for the version. so 5_0_1 instead of just 5_0 so i had to modify this to navigator.userAgent.match(/OS 5_\d_\d like Mac OS X/i)

Comment: Just a note: because sometimes iOS5 returns a solid versions number as in 5_0 and sometimes a sub version number 5_0_1 neither 5_\d or 5_\d_\d accurately detects iOS5 in all instances. I propose: navigator.userAgent.match(/OS 5_.*\ like Mac OS X/i);

Comment: my take: navigator.userAgent.match(/OS 5(_\d)+ like Mac OS X/i)

Answer (score 3):

I've developed chown's answer a bit further, with a check for any iOS5 device, be it 5 or 5.0.1 or any later versions:

```
var ios5 = navigator.userAgent.match(/OS 5_[0-9_]+ like Mac OS X/i) != null;
if(ios5) {
    // Now you can do specific stuff for devices on any version of iOS5
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to account for "CPU OS 5_0" and "CPU iPhone OS 5_0", rough and dirty regex:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone);.*CPU.*OS 5_\d/i))
{ 
   alert("On iOS 5")
}
else
{
   alert("Not on iOS 5"); //could be either 4- or 6+
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could be using [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/) and detecting for [Web Workers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Workers) as they were not available prior to iOS 5. You need to still exclude Android as Android 2.0+ has supported them. This will give you forward compatibility with iOS6 which you aren't going to get with either of the user agent parses already provided.

Comment: Further, neither other answer handles 5.0.x, 5.1.x, etc.