# user - agent ios 5.0?

Tags: iphone, webview, user-agent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the iOS 5.0 user agent string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825873/what-is-the-ios-5-0-user-agent-string)

I want a mobile page in web-view

So, I recognize the device (=iphone)

3gs iost 5.0. what user-agent?

NSMutableURLRequest *request = (NSMutableURLRequest *)req;

```
 if ([request respondsToSelector:@selector(setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:)]) 
 {
```

[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ **Mozilla/5.0

   (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko)        Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3**", [request valueForHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"User_Agent"];
    }
    return YES; 
}

bold area. I want a correct user-agent.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>**iOS 5.0**</sup>

iPhone:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3
```

iPad:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3
```

---

<sup>**iOS 5.1**</sup>

iPhone:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B176 Safari/7534.48.3
```

iPad:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B176 Safari/7534.48.3
```