# Opening a website as an iPad/iPhone in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, mobile-website, m3u

I'm trying to parse  streaming video websites in order to play them in an iPad/iPhone app.
For example, in www.veetle.com, opening a channel with an iPad or iPhone you can see the video, because the code for this finds a .m3u (or .m3u8) file which can be played. But opening from a computer browser, or parsing the channel address in Xcode doesn't show you this .m3u file, it uses flash.

What I want is to get this .m3u file to be able to play the channel, I have been searching all around the web how to open a website as a mobile in Xcode, but I haven't found anything. Any idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the so called [user agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) string in your request.

See here: [Changing the userAgent of NSURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532206/changing-the-useragent-of-nsurlconnection)
and here: [What is the iOS 5.0 user agent string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825873/what-is-the-ios-5-0-user-agent-string)

Developer tools for safari also offers the ability so quickly change the user agent which is nice if you just want to quickly check a site: http://designshack.net/articles/developer-tools-in-safari/

Use eg this to see your current user agent: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=user+agent+

Comment: Thanks,that worked perfectly. For some servers this was enough, however, in veetle, I can't get the file from the code source, I have to go to the web inspector of safari to find the .m3u. Is there a way to do this in Xcode?

Comment: Sorry, cannot help you with this since I don't know what veetle does differently. Maybe consider asking a new question containing additional information about your problem with veetle.