# Make a web browser navigate to mobile phone site

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, web

I'm building a windows form using a web browser.
I have a URL and I want the web browser to display the mobile site.
For example:

If I type: www.facebook.com,
I want the web browser to navigate to: m.facebook.com.
How do I pretend to be a mobile phone?
I don't know what I need to do to solve my problem.
I'm using Visual Studio 2012 - winform - c#.

I tried this:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers["User-Agent"] = "myUserAgentString";
```

Comment: Okay. So you tried that. What happened? Is `"myUserAgentString"` the actual value you used? What other user agent strings have you tried

Answer (score 4):

I know this is about a year old, but this is an easy thing to do:

First you need the user agent string and it needs to be string formatted.
This is how I do it below

```
wbMobile.Navigate(new Uri("http://m.bing.com/", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute), string.Empty, null, string.Format("User-Agent: {0}", "Opera/9.80 (J2ME/MIDP; Opera Mini/9 (Compatible; MSIE:9.0; iPhone; BlackBerry9700; AppleWebKit/24.746; U; en) Presto/2.5.25 Version/10.54"));
```

This will navigate to the webpage using a mobile user agent string and allow you to view mobile websites on the fly in the webbrowser control

Answer (score 0):

I used something like this: (JavaScript)

```
<script>
if (document.location.search.indexOf('skipmobile') >= 0) {
    document.cookie = 'skipmobile=1';
}
else if ((document.location.hostname.match(/\.mobi$/) || screen.width < 799)
&& document.cookie.indexOf('skipmobile') == -1)
{
    document.location = 'm/';
}
</script>
```

In other words, if screen display is under 799px, redirect user to the mobile version, which was  mysite.com/m/

Comment: i want to pretend to be a mobile phone and not to check if a site is for mobile phone.... and i don't use javascript in my code...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the user agent string for iphone ios5

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3
```

From: [What is the iOS 5.0 user agent string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825873/what-is-the-ios-5-0-user-agent-string)

Comment: can you be more detailed? can you write exactlly what i need to write?

Comment: @user3461486 client.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3"

Comment: still don't work. how do i combined what you gave me with the http request from the site (for requesting the source code)?

Comment: Use something like wireshark to check the full set of headers a mobile device sends. Send the same, and you should receive a mobile version of the site.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the code you need from [detectmobilebrowsers.com](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/)

You can the use [F12 developer tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn255001%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in IE 10+ to emulate mobile browsers.