# Htaccess redirections depending on OS

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, server

1- I need the .htaccess code for this condition If the user clicked on:
website1.download
OR
website2.download
It redirects the user depending on his OS for example:

- If on PC, redirect to http://google.com/
- If on Android, redirect to https://play.google.com/store
- If on iOS, redirect to https://www.apple.com/ios/app-store/

2- I've more than one website in my host and I need to create a one .htaccess to all websites in the host, where I can create the .htaccess file?

That is the htaccess codes and it's not working:

```
<If "req('Host') = 'website1.download' && = 'website2.download'">
    # turn on rewrite engine
    RewriteEngine on

    # only detect smart phone devices if we are not on mobile site
    # to prevent redirect looping
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^https://google.com/$

    # Android
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android" [NC]
    # redirect to google play
    RewriteRule .? https://play.google.com/store%{REQUEST_URI}  [L,R=302]

    # iOS
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android" [NC]
    # redirect to app store
    RewriteRule .? https://www.apple.com/ios/app-store/%{REQUEST_URI}  [L,R=302]
</If>
```

Comment: To be clear, you own/control the domains `google.download` and `yahoo.download`? Or are those examples?

Comment: No, (google.download and yahoo.download) it just examples

Comment: Updated (google.download and yahoo.download) examples to website1 and website2

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm going with `example.com` and `example.net` since that's what they are for. Also, I'm assuming these domains point to your server and they have all been bound to it, too. Lastly, I'm assuming you have a pattern already for device detection? It isn't super clear in your question. (If you don't you can probably just base this off [Google](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7825873/231316).)

You can just stack `RewriteCond` and join them with an `OR`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.net [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android" [NC]
RewriteRule .? https://play.google.com/store%{REQUEST_URI}  [L,R=302]
```

Technically that is a regex, too, so some care should be taken for special characters as well as being more specific, adding subdomain support and just merging everything into a single condition.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.(com|net)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android" [NC]
RewriteRule .? https://play.google.com/store%{REQUEST_URI}  [L,R=302]
```

There's [`HTTP_HOST` vs `SERVER_NAME`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2297403/231316) that you should be aware of, too.

All that said, I can't think of a good reason to do this. From an SEO-perspective, you are going to wind up hiding 2 out of 3 redirects because spiders store information they find at a given URL, and if that changes, the most recent change wins. From a user-perspective,   people are mostly trained to click the badges from the stores, I wouldn't introduce something new and weird. If you are trying to track a click, I'd just use JS.