# Check for iOS native smart banner support

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios

iOS6 supports native smart banners in browser. I was trying to fallback if smart banner is not supported then show my own banner. Does anyone know how to check in js if browser has support for native iOS smart banners.

Details on smart banners : [enter link description here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html)

Comment: Why not check the OS version and go from there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814984/detect-ios5-within-mobile-safari-javascript-preferred

Comment: thats a work around but I like feature sniffing rather than browser sniffing.

Comment: Yeah I was going to say that in my comment that it's not the best way to go about it...that's why I posted as a comment rather than an answer lol. Will see if I can dig something up.

Comment: Though I appreciate for your help.